# CountUp time in android application

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an Age calculator App for android devices and in this app right now I get the birth date and current date then I get the difference of those times and I show it to the user.

Problem is that I am looking for a way to add a countUp feature for the Age calculator which counts up the timer of the user's Age (LIKE LIVE AGING :D).

Here is my Age calculator class :

```
public class AgeCalculation {
    private int startYear;
    private int startMonth;
    private int startDay;
    private int endYear;
    private int endMonth;
    private int endDay;
    private int resYear;
    private int resMonth;
    private int resDay;
    private Calendar start;
    private Calendar end;
    public String getCurrentDate()
    {
          end=Calendar.getInstance();
          endYear=end.get(Calendar.YEAR);
          endMonth=end.get(Calendar.MONTH);
          endMonth++;
          endDay=end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
          return endDay+":"+endMonth+":"+endYear;
    }
    public void setDateOfBirth(int sYear, int sMonth, int sDay)
    {
     startYear=sYear;
     startMonth=sMonth;
     startMonth++;
     startDay=sDay;

    }
    public void calcualteYear()
    {
        resYear=endYear-startYear;

    }

    public void calcualteMonth()
    {
        if(endMonth>=startMonth)
        {
             resMonth= endMonth-startMonth;
        }
        else
        {
            resMonth=endMonth-startMonth;
            resMonth=12+resMonth;
            resYear--;
        }

    }
    public void  calcualteDay()
    {

        if(endDay>=startDay)
        {
             resDay= endDay-startDay;
        }
        else
        {
            resDay=endDay-startDay;
            resDay=30+resDay;
            if(resMonth==0)
            {
                resMonth=11;
                resYear--;
            }
            else
            {
                resMonth--;
            }

        }
    }

    public String getResult()
    {
        return  resYear + " year  " + resMonth + " month  " + resDay + " day " ;
    }
     public long getSeconde()
     {
         start=Calendar.getInstance();
         start.set(Calendar.YEAR, startYear);
         start.set(Calendar.MONTH, startMonth);
         start.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, startDay);
         start.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
         start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
         start.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
         start.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 30);
         long now=end.getTimeInMillis();
         long old=start.getTimeInMillis();
         long diff=old-now;
         return diff/1000;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a timer, that each second (or whatever) increments a value, that you then show in a text field. Something along the lines of:

```
public void ageTimer() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                liveAge++
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }
```

You could then append this to Years, Days etc. Add in your own checks for when it hits 60 seconds and then increment minute etc.

You could then display it in a text field like so:

```
yourAge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourAge); // where yourAge is the id of your textview in xml
yourAge.setText(liveAge);
```

Comment: If you're using Eclipse on Windows you can do: `Ctrl+Shift+O` to auto import for you or just: `import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;`